# Publish local ingested products and not using s3 bucket in [datacube-ows]

Tags: wms, open-data-cube, ows

I am interested in publishing ingested product in my local Opendatacube instance. Everything working fine.
As far I know datacube-ows provides capabilities to offer OGC web services. Reading its configuration to the section

```
ows_cfg = {
"wms": {
        # Provide S3 data URL, bucket name for data_links in GetFeatureinfo responses
        # Note that this feature is currently restricted to data stored in AWS S3.
        # This feature is also fairly specialised to DEA requirements and may not be suited to more general use.
        # All Optional
        # Config for WMS service, for all products/layers
        "s3_aws_zone": "af-south-1",
        "max_width": 512,
        "max_height": 512,
    },
```

The 'wms' section says that it need to have s3 URLs. My query is can't we publish  products ingested at our local instance of datacube (products saved at local filesystem).
Any hints how to specify in ows-configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify those S3 URLs.

For Datacube OWS to be able to render and produce WMS/WCS/WMTS tiles, you only need to have the data working in the Open Data Cube. If you can load it with ODC, it will work in OWS.

There are a lot of config examples here: [DEA Config](https://github.com/GeoscienceAustralia/dea-config/tree/master/prod/services/wms/ows_refactored). Or read the [docs, here](https://readthedocs.org/projects/datacube-ows/).